# jquery $.ajax force POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get

I have an ajax function that creates a link that triggers another ajax function. For some reason the second ajax function refuses to go through POST event if I've set `type: "POST"`

The two functionas are below:

```
function HandleActivateLink(source) {
            var url = source.attr('href');
            window.alert(url)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                success: function (server_response) {
                    window.alert("well done")
                }
            });
            return false;
    }


    function HandleDeleteLink() {
        $('a.delete-link').click(function () {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var the_link = $(this)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // GET or POST
                url: url, // the file to call
                success: function (server_response) {
                    if (server_response.object_deleted) {
                        FlashMessage('#form-success', 'Link Deleted <a class="activate-link" href="' + url.replace('delete', 'activate') + '">Undo</a>');
                        $('a.activate-link').click(function(){
                            HandleActivateLink($(this));
                        });

                        the_link.parent().hide();
                    } else {
                        var form_errors = server_response.errors;
                        alert(form_errors)
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

You'll notice `HandleDeleteLink` creates a new link on success, and generates a new click event for the created link. It all works but`HandleActivateLink` sends the request to the server as `GET`. I've tried using `$.post` instead with no luck.

Any pointers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second event you do not inform the client to prevent the default behaviour.

One way to do this would be to change:

```
$('a.activate-link').click(function(){
                            HandleActivateLink($(this));
                        });
```

to:

```
$('a.activate-link').click(function(){
                            return HandleActivateLink($(this));
                        });
```

(This works because `HandleActiveLink` already returns false.)

A nicer way to do this is to pass in the event argument to the click function and tell it to `preventDefault`

```
$('a.activate-link').click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            HandleActivateLink($(this));
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your url?
btw You can't send a cross-domain post via javascript.